# visitor pattern for template derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, derived, visitor-pattern

Related question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771928/c-custom-class-identification-for-derived-classes).

In one of the answers to the question above, I was recommended to use the visitor pattern to resolve some of the issues with my class inheritance structure. However, I am not sure if it is possible to use it in my context because my derived classes can be non-type templates.

To showcase the problem I used a modified code from this source: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/2.
The example below does not compile because it is not possible to define a virtual template method. However, I believe, the code demonstrates what I am trying to achieve. Are there any alternatives solutions to the problem?

```
// 1. Add an accept(Visitor) method to the "element" hierarchy
class Element
{
  public:
    virtual void accept(class Visitor &v) = 0;
};

template <unsigned int N>
class This: public Element
{
  public:
     /*virtual*/void accept(Visitor &v);
    string thiss()
    {
        return "This";
    }
};

class That: public Element
{
  public:
     /*virtual*/void accept(Visitor &v);
    string that()
    {
        return "That";
    }
};

// 2. Create a "visitor" base class w/ a visit() method for every "element" type
class Visitor
{
  public:
    template<unsigned int N>
    virtual void visit(This<N> *e) = 0;
    virtual void visit(That *e) = 0;

};

 template<unsigned int N>
 /*virtual*/void This<N>::accept(Visitor &v)
{
  v.visit(this);
}

 /*virtual*/void That::accept(Visitor &v)
{
  v.visit(this);
}

// 3. Create a "visitor" derived class for each "operation" to do on "elements"
class UpVisitor: public Visitor
{
     /*virtual*/void visit(This *e)
    {
        cout << "do Up on " + e->thiss() << '\n';
    }
     /*virtual*/void visit(That *e)
    {
        cout << "do Up on " + e->that() << '\n';
    }

};

class DownVisitor: public Visitor
{
     /*virtual*/void visit(This *e)
    {
        cout << "do Down on " + e->thiss() << '\n';
    }
     /*virtual*/void visit(That *e)
    {
        cout << "do Down on " + e->that() << '\n';
    }

}; 

    int main() 
    {

        Element *list[] = 
        {
            new This<3>(), new That()
        };
        UpVisitor up; // 4. Client creates
         DownVisitor down; //    "visitor" objects
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) list[i]->accept(up);
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) list[i]->accept(down);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `Visitor` class is tightly coupled with classes that derive from `Element`. As you expand your design this is going to get in the way more than it already is. You can reduce/eliminate the right coupling by providing a "destination" class that defines all the requirements of a visitable object. Since the name of a derived classes is a common attribute you can place the storage and access to it into the destination class as well.

```
// 1. Define out visitor and destination interfaces
struct Destination
{
    Destination(const std::string& name) : name_(name) {}
    virtual std::string ident() const { return name_; }

    const std::string name_;
};

struct Visitor
{
    virtual void visit(Destination *e) = 0;
};
```

This keeps the requirements of the visitor separate from the Element class which seems to be your intention. Then your `This` and `That` classes inherit from `Destination` and provide the necessary implementations.

```
// 2. Define our element and it's derived classes
class Element
{
public:
    virtual void accept(class Visitor &v) = 0;
};

template <unsigned int N>
class This: public Element, public Destination
{
public:
    This() : Destination("This") {}
    virtual void accept(Visitor &v)
    {
        v.visit(this);
    }
};

class That: public Element, public Destination
{
public:
    That() : Destination("That") {}
    virtual void accept(Visitor &v)
    {
        v.visit(this);
    }
};
```

Now your up and down visitors are simplified into something like the following

```
// 3. Create a "visitor" derived class for each "operation" to do on "elements"
class UpVisitor: public Visitor
{
    void visit(Destination *e) {
        cout << "do Up on " + e->ident() << '\n';
    }
};

class DownVisitor: public Visitor
{
    void visit(Destination *e) {
        cout << "do Down on " + e->ident() << '\n';
    }
};
```

Although I did not change it in the solution above I recommend changing `visit` to take a reference instead of a pointer. Since C++ has no notion of a null reference this indicates that `Destination` is *required* where as a pointer could be considered *optional*.